# Extent report overwritting issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, testng-eclipse, selenium-extent-report

I'm using extent report 5.0.9 while running my script I have no issue in testng. It worked as expected. While generating extent report it overwritting with another test case. Eg i have written 23 test cases but in extent report it only shows 21 cases. Two cases overwritting with other test case. Kindly help me out from this.

```
enter code here

package Testcases;import org.testng.annotations.Test;import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ViewName;import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest; public class sample2 {
ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test; @BeforeTest
public void startReport() {

htmlReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +".//test-output//Report12.html");
extent = new ExtentReports();
extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter); 
htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report");
htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Test report");
htmlReporter.config().setTimeStampFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a '('zzz')'");
htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
} @Test
public void test_1() {
test = extent.createTest("Test Case 1", "The test case 1 has passed");
Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
@Test
public void test_2() {
test = extent.createTest("Test Case 2", "The test case 2 has failed");
Assert.assertTrue(false);
} @Test
public void test_3() {
test = extent.createTest("Test Case 3", "The test case 3 has been skipped");
throw new SkipException("The test has been skipped");
} @AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) {
if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
test.log(Status.FAIL,result.getThrowable());
}
else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
test.log(Status.PASS, result.getTestName());
}
else {
test.log(Status.SKIP, result.getTestName());
}
} @AfterTest
public void tearDown() {
extent.flush();
}
}
```

Comment: can you paste the code which u tried in order to understand what went wrong

Comment: i have added the sample code